# Framework to host web services on a basic hosted web server

Tags: mysql, service, hosting

Can anyone recommend a framework or basic technology to use to host a web service on a basic hosted web server?

I have data in a mySQL database that will be accessed by the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create them very easily in C#